# Read internal counters of USB scanning device

Tags: c#, usb, counter, device

I am trying to programmatically access internal device counters of a document scanning device that is connected via USB to my computer. I am NOT interested in the data that a scanner normally outputs (content of scanned pages, etc)! Instead, I would like to know how many pages were scanned so far. Does anyone have a clue on how to access such data? SNMP is usually the way to go for such device counters, but not with USB devices (at least I am not aware of how to do it).

OS is Windows 7, programming language is C#, and the scanning device is a Canon DR-M160 (hopefully this shouldn't matter, as I try to create a vendor-independend solution).

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744499/snmp-for-local-printer

Comment: I am sorry, I am not allowed to install third-party software alongside with what I am trying to achieve. So, hopefully, someone knows how to get these values from the device directly. In the meantime, I took a look at WIA, which allows to get and set values, but unfortunately, there seems to be no way of reading the number of scanned pages :(

I can see the number of scanned pages in Windows Control panel -> Devices -> Scan Properties of my Canon scanner. Is this value read from the driver directly?